# Text processor that is capable of Arabic

Tags: windows, text-processing

I want to create some documents with Arabic text in them. I already tried several programs, but not of them can satisfy my needs, which I think are quite basic.

I want:

- Multi-column text layout
- Numbered lists with Eastern Arabic digits (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩)
- Correct display of glyphs depending on context
- Tashkil, since I write texts for beginner learners
- Formatting styles, so that I don't have to do the formatting individually
- A program that runs on Microsoft Windows 10

I tried Microsoft Word 2010, which gets the job almost done, it just [causes the wrong glyphs to be displayed](https://superuser.com/questions/1210308/arabic-letter-heh-%D9%87-is-rendered-incorrectly-in-calibri-font).

I tried Microsoft Word 2016, which [doesn't get the spacing of the letters correctly](https://softwarerant.blogspot.de/2017/05/arabisch-schreiben-in-microsoft-word.html) (see the third screenshot).

I tried Scribus, which [cannot display Arabic text properly at all](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=14825).

I tried Microsoft WordPad, which lacks formatting possibilities like text in multiple columns.

I tried LibreOffice 5.2, which cannot format a numbered list so that the numbers appear in Eastern Arabic digits (no bug report yet for this one).

Any idea which other programs I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [SummitSoft Arabic Editor](http://www.summitsoft.co.uk/pages/Compare-Arabic-Editor/Compare-Arabic-Editor.html) as it handles Arabic in just about every way imaginable.